# Conditionals, Variables, and Views

Tags: swift, swiftui

New to Swift and having trouble finding the solution to this. It's probably a simple fix, that I haven't been able to figure out.

This program takes user input in a TextField and reacts based on that input (if input is a number, or not a number, and how many characters the input is).

I'm trying to figure out how to reassign the variable **px** within the conditional statements in order to vary font size.

Code below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var p: String = ""
    @State var px: Int = 35
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0.0) {
            if p.isNotNum {
                if p.count > 10 {
                    px = 20 \\ this breaks
                }
                Text(String(p))
                    .font(.system(size: CGFloat(px)))
            } else if p.isNum {
                if p.count > 10 {
                    px = 20 \\ this breaks
                }
                Text(String(p))
            }
            TextField("P", text: $p)
        }
    }
}

extension String {
    var isNum: Bool {
        return Double(self) != nil
    }
}

extension String {
    var isNotNum: Bool {
        return Double(self) == nil
    }
}
```

Comment: "This breaks" Breaks how?

Comment: Also, it's odd to have a boolean property for a specific condition, and it's opposite. It's even more odd to then check the first, and then also its opposite (if `p.isNotNum` is false, then `p.isNum` is surely true, and you don't need to check). Consider simplying to just `if p.isNum { ... } else { ... }`

Comment: You cannot have this type of code `px = 20` anywhere you want in a View, it is only allowed 
 in certain places. I suggest you read the basics of SwiftUI: https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/  to 
 understand this fundamental concept. Note that your code `logic` is very much well below average.

Comment: follow this nice free online course first https://cs193p.sites.stanford.edu/

Comment: Indeed it is odd in places, this is a paraphrase of a larger codebase where these checks are needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body property is a [view builder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/viewbuilder) and system get new views as dependencies change ( here @State ) by calling this get {} property.

It's clear to use `.onChange`  if you wanna do some changes based on @State property change .

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var p: String = ""
    @State var px: Int = 35
    
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0.0) {
            if p.isNum {
                Text(String(p))
                    
            } else  {
                Text(String(p))
                    .font(.system(size: CGFloat(px)))
            }
            TextField("placeholder p ", text: $p)
        }
        .onChange(of: p, perform: { // <= here
            if $0.count > 10 {
                px = 20
            } else if p.count > 10 {
                px = 20
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use imperative code like `px = 20` in the middle of your view hierarchy because it doesn't return a `View`

Use `onChange` instead:

```swift
.onChange(p) {
    if $0.count > 10 {
        px = 20
    } else if p.count > 10 {
        px = 20
    }
}
```

Also, you can execute the code in `some View` by assigning a constant. For example:

```swift
let _ = { px = 20 }
```